# SQL statement to generate a column whose value is the record index

Tags: sql, range, idioms, monetdb, iota

I have some SQL table, say with a single column c1:

| c1 |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| 10 |
| 5 |

Now, I'd like to issue an SQL command (not some operation of my DBMS, which I have intentionally not mentioned) which causes my table to be:

| c1 | record_index |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |

Very simple... can this be done? Obviously, you don't know in advance the length of the table, so no SQL insertion or similar tricks.

**Note:** I'd like a general answer, but to be specific - I'm working with [MonetDB](http://www.monetdb.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [@a_horse_with_no_name 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853947/1593077)...:

```
SELECT 
  c1, 
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dummy)-1 AS record_index
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    c1,
    42 AS dummy 
  FROM t1
) AS t1_augmented;
```

<sub>(Noting of course that row_number()'s result is 1-based.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "row index" in a relational database (note that a relation database contains rows, not "records"), but if you can find a column by which to sort the result this can easily be done using a window function:

```
select c1,
       row_number() over (order by some_column) as record_index
from the_table
order by record_index;
```

(You didn't specify your DBMS, the above is ANSI SQL)

**Edit**

if you don't have a column to sort on, you can try sorting by a constant value instead which will bring back the rows "unordered":

```
select record_index,
       row_number() over (order by 42) as record_index
from the_table
order by record_index;
```

But again: there is no such thing as a "natural" order of rows. There *might* be one on disk, but that is most likely not the one that is being used during retrieval - especially when the table doesn't have a clustered index (Oracle does not use a clustered index by default, Postgres doesn't have them at all).

A DBMS might also apply additional optimizations when *retrieving* the data. Oracle, Postgres and I believe SQL Server as well can e.g. "hop" on a table scan from a different session to optimize the phyiscal read from disk. In that case two concurrent selects will show a different "order" even though the *phyiscal* layout on the harddisk didn't change.

And then you have changes to the physical storage due to updates (e.g. if a row doesn't fit on the block any longer because its size increased).

Comment: The column to sort by appears to be the OP's biggest challenge.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall': yes, absolutely. But without more information about the *actual* problem, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Well, there are no other columns. I know the order is not intrinsic to the relation - but, an RDBMS eventually has to order its output _somehow_, and I want to catch _that_ order.

Comment: @einpoklum: there is no "that order". Modern DBMS apply several optimizations when retrieving data, so the order you see *now* is not necessarily the order you see with the next statement e.g. due to synchronized table scans - and I'm not even talking about physical changes to the storage due to DML. You can however try to use `order by null` in the window definition.

Comment: I can't `order by 42` in MonetDB... nor can I `order by null`... is that standard SQL?